# Displaying different modern icons in Ribbon Workbench for command bar or fly-out menu in UCI Dynamics 365 V9

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, crm-ribbon-workbench, dynamics-crm-365-v9, dynamics-crm-uci

Using Ribbon Workbench 2016 (3.1.177.1).

I'm fairly new to this, but I've successfully created a button for the unified interface which performs as expected.

However, the icon I've selected is white on a transparent background - as I believe it should be.

This works fine for the UI on desktop, which renders the command bar with a blue background.

However, when used on a phone, all commands appear in the "More Commands" flyout with a white background so the icon is not visible, as it is white on white.

I had a look at the display/enable rules, and couldn't see an appropriate option (CommandClientTypeRule only offers 'Modern, 'Refresh' and 'Legacy').

Is there a way for me to specify an image to use in the Modern interface in Phone layout? Or a way to show a different button if it is in the context of a flyout?

Thanks

Comment: UII uses SVG images, there should be a dedicated entry for it in the workbench but I don't have it at hand so I can't be more precise

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes this is an issue with using the correctly configured SVG image.

Comment: Can you share some screenshot to explain your problem?

Comment: Thanks, @Alex !!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the unified interface uses SVG image for Ribbon icons. 
It can be set under ModernImage option in Ribbon Workbench after uploading in Dynamics CRM web resource. 
[image]